# Python MultiProcessing Pool Slower Than Sequential?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

So I've been playing around with the **`multiprocessing`** module, trying to figure out ways to speed up a lot of the work I do with `pandas` DataFrames.

The example I was working with was taking a sequence of Excel files, each one representing a years worth of data, turning them into a dataframe and then summing one of the columns. Sequentially, something like this:

```
now = time.time()
dict = {}
table_2010 = pd.read_excel('2010.xlsx')
table_2011 = pd.read_excel('2011.xlsx')
table_2012 = pd.read_excel('2012.xlsx')
table_2013 = pd.read_excel('2013.xlsx')
table_2014 = pd.read_excel('2014.xlsx')
table_2015 = pd.read_excel('2015.xlsx')
dict[2011] = table_2011[[95]].sum()
dict[2010] = table_2010[[95]].sum()
dict[2012] = table_2012[[95]].sum()
dict[2013] = table_2013[[95]].sum()
dict[2014] = table_2014[[95]].sum()
dict[2015] = table_2015[[95]].sum()
print dict
print time.time() - now
```

This took me **205 seconds**, the Excel files are sizable and take a while to load into a dataframe, and I assumed that running it in **parallel** would improve that performance. What I came up with was this:

```
def func(year):
    table = pd.read_excel(str(year) + '.xlsx')
    dict[year] = table[[95]].sum()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    now = time.time()
    dict = {}
    pool = ThreadPool(8)
    pool.map_async(func, [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print dict
    print time.time() - now
```

When I ran this though, it ended up taking **250 seconds**. It was my impression that having separate cores run each of these processes would improve performance, is that incorrect?

Or is there an issue with the script I wrote?

Comment: Assuming all your excel files are on the same physical device (harddrive) then splitting out the loading of the data from them will not provide any performance gain, as the threads will be competing for IO access (and it may in certain cases even be slower than sequential access). The actual calculation of the sums should be faster though

Comment: Your bottleneck is going to most likely be your hard disk. If you have 8 threads fighting for read access, then each time one grants access it will waste cycles waiting for the next bit of read for it's data.

Comment: Interesting, so in a situation like this, it would make more sense to read them all sequentially and then perform whatever calculations in parallel?

Comment: Yes, unless you can load from different physical devices.

Answer (score -1):

<sup>Slower?
Depends.
Depends, **a lot**.

Is there an issue with the script?
**Yes, a brute one** ( still no need to worry or panic - a well solvable one ). **Enjoy the read.**</sup>

```
# =========================================================================[sec]
  an-<iterator>-based SERIAL processing of 9 CPU-bound tasks took 1290.538 [sec]
 aThreadPool(6)-based  TPOOL processing of 9 CPU-bound tasks took 1212.065 [sec]
       aPool(6)-based   POOL processing of 9 CPU-bound tasks took  271.765 [sec]
# =========================================================================[sec]
```

### Python `multiprocessing` has several `Pool`-s

Based on not a fully documented MCVE-above ( missing all explicit namespace `import`-s to safely disambiguate the setup for an intended use-case), let's start with your code mentioning **`ThreadPool.map_async()`** and processing many Excel files.

One could hardly start a worse approach for the intended fast processing.

---

### Is a `Pool` slower than `SEQ`?

Having purposely borrowed a natively-parallel **`occam`**-language syntax, the question tends to lead to the pain of a **`PAR`** | **`SEQ`** dilemma in designing high-performance systems ( Yes, HPC, sure - guess, who would ever like to design slow systems on purpose, right? ).

**The issue is sufficiently multi-fold** to ask even more questions before being able to seriously approach the answer to the initial dilemma.

What **resources** do we have?

What **type of operations** are to be executed in a **`PAR`** | **`SEQ`** arrangement:

- is the problem  purely { CPU-bound | IO-bound }?
- is the problem in a need to share-{ state | data } during processing?
- is the problem in a need to communicate-{ signals | messages } during processing?

---

### Let's start with prototyped use-cases:

A CPU-bound processing is much simpler to mock-up ( and a way "greener" to wear & tear precious physical HPC resources ), so let's start to use a primitive function:

```
def aFatCALCULUS( id ):                         # an INTENSIVE CPU-bound WORKLOAD
    import numpy as np
    import os
    pass;   aST = "aFatCALCULUS( {1:>3d} ) [PID:: {0:d}] RET'd {2:d}"
    return( aST.format( os.getpid(),
                        id,
                        id + len( str( [ np.math.factorial( 2**f ) for f in range( 20 ) ][-1] ) )
                        )
            )
```

Now, let's execute this one several times, in different arrangements.

Forgive my non-PEP-8 format ( we do not sponsor any core refactoring with the demonstrations made here, so indeed nobody serious shall ever feel this choice inappropriate in whatever sense ).

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool                             # ThreadPool-mode
from multiprocessing      import Pool                                   #       Pool-mode
pass;                     import time
print( "{0:}----------------------------------------------------------- # SETUP:".format(                                   time.ctime() ) )
aListOfTaskIdNUMBERs = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ]

print( "{0:}----------------------------------------------------------- # PROCESSING-ThreadPool mode of EXECUTION:".format( time.ctime() ) )
aTPool = ThreadPool( 6 )                                                # PROCESSING-ThreadPool.capacity == 6

print( "{0:}----------------------------------------------------------- # SERIAL mode of EXECUTION:".format( time.ctime() ) )
start  = time.clock_gettime( time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW );
pass;                                                  [ aFatCALCULUS( id ) for id in aListOfTaskIdNUMBERs ] # SERIAL <iterator>-driven mode of EXECUTION
pass;                                                                   duration = time.clock_gettime( time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW ) - start; print( "an-<iterator>-based SERIAL processing of {1:}-tasks took {0:} [sec]".format( duration, len( aListOfTaskIdNUMBERs ) ) )
pass;

print( "{0:}----------------------------------------------------------- # PROCESSING-Pool mode of EXECUTION:".format( time.ctime() ) )
aPool  = Pool( 6 )                                                      # PROCESSING-Pool.capacity == 6
start  = time.clock_gettime( time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW );
pass;                                                 aPool.map( aFatCALCULUS, aListOfTaskIdNUMBERs )        # PROCESSING-Pool-driven mode of EXECUTION
pass;                                                                   duration = time.clock_gettime( time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW ) - start; print( "aPool(6)-based processing of {1:}-tasks took {0:} [sec]".format( duration, len( aListOfTaskIdNUMBERs ) ) )
print( "{0:}----------------------------------------------------------- # END.".format( time.ctime() ) )
```

### Why?  <sub>. . . just check the `PID`#s</sub>

```
aPool(6).map()
["aFatCALCULUS(   1 ) [PID:: 898] RET'd 2771011",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   2 ) [PID:: 899] RET'd 2771012",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   3 ) [PID:: 900] RET'd 2771013",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   4 ) [PID:: 901] RET'd 2771014",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   5 ) [PID:: 902] RET'd 2771015",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   6 ) [PID:: 903] RET'd 2771016",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   7 ) [PID:: 898] RET'd 2771017",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   8 ) [PID:: 899] RET'd 2771018",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   9 ) [PID:: 903] RET'd 2771019"
 ]

aThreadPool(6)
["aFatCALCULUS(   1 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771011",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   2 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771012",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   3 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771013",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   4 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771014",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   5 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771015",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   6 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771016",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   7 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771017",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   8 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771018",
 "aFatCALCULUS(   9 ) [PID:: 16125] RET'd 2771019"
 ]
```

---

### How to best orchestrate the IO-bound case?

> ---
>
> A supercomputer turns compute-bound problems into I/O bound problems ( S. Cray )
>
> ---

**Obey Seymour CRAY's wisdom** with all due humility,
**but**
**do not let others make you the one,
who pays the costs of their missing HPC duties**
on your side of the CPU-budget.

IMHO, if this were my HPC-task,
I would

- avoid paying **`pandas`** XLSX-import / transformation costs
- make Excel-data-**owner** / **processor** to guarrantee and enforce their automated column-**`SUM()`**-{ auto | manual | scripted }-**update** on each data-element change/update arriving in time, be it in batch or by an event, on their data-store side
- go for the fastest ( distributed-processing ) architecture with the powers of independent `multiprocessing.Pool().map()` processes not reading ( == moving all heaps of data ) but using a smart, direct-access, just to cells ( == elements ) you need to process.

### Here,
everyone can see and smell
why a **`PAR`** arranged **`Pool()`** is faster than any other **`SEQ`** processing:

```
'''     REAL SYSTEM:: multiprocessing.Pool(6).map()
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

top - 22:24:42 up 84 days, 23:05,  4 users,  load average: 4.80, 2.17, 0.86
Threads: 366 total,   5 running, 361 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  75.7/0.0    76[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                        ]
%Cpu1  :   0.1/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu2  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu3  : 100.0/0.0   100[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]
%Cpu4  :   0.1/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu5  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu6  :  76.2/0.0    76[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                        ]
%Cpu7  : 100.0/0.0   100[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]
%Cpu8  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu9  :  75.5/0.0    76[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                        ]
%Cpu10 :   0.5/0.4     1[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu11 : 100.0/0.0   100[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]
%Cpu12 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu13 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu14 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu15 :   0.7/0.5     1[||                                                                                                  ]
%Cpu16 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu17 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu18 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu19 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
KiB Mem : 24522940 total, 22070528 free,   778080 used,  1674332 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8257532 total,  7419136 free,   838396 used. 22905264 avail Mem

 P S %CPU  PPID   PID nTH     TIME+ USER      PR  NI    RES   CODE    SHR    DATA %MEM    VIRT vMj vMn   SWAP      nsIPC COMMAND
 1 S  0.0  1614  1670   1  10:54.15 root      20   0    632    740    416    1396  0.0   52140   0   0   1172 -                   `- haproxy
 2 S  0.0  1614  1671   1  35:40.50 root      20   0    664    740    380    1528  0.0   52272   0   0   1172 -                   `- haproxy
19 S  0.0     1  1658   1   6:20.42 root      20   0  22960    468  14380   14240  0.1  466344   0   0    836 -           `- httpd
12 S  0.0     1 24217   1   4:31.41 root      20   0   3984      8    668    7320  0.0  155304   0   0   3864 -           `- munin-node
 0 R  0.0 12882  4964   1   0:31.53 m         20   0   2596     96   1524    1596  0.0  158096   0   0      0 4026531839                  `- top
 0 S  0.1 15213 22779  22   0:11.16 m         20   0  54052   2268   5816 1965528  0.2 2191768   0   0      0 4026531839                      `- python3
 1 S  0.1 15213 23613  22   0:10.83 m         20   0  54052   2268   5816 1965528  0.2 2191768   0   0      0 4026531839                      `- python3
 7 R 99.9 16125   898   1   2:29.72 m         20   0  52084   2268   1336 1969112  0.2 2195352   0  3k      0 4026531839                      `- python3
11 R 99.9 16125   899   1   2:29.72 m         20   0  52088   2268   1336 1969116  0.2 2195356   0  3k      0 4026531839                      `- python3
 6 S 76.3 16125   900   1   2:15.49 m         20   0  49724   2268   1236 1965520  0.2 2191760   0 777      0 4026531839                      `- python3
 0 S 75.7 16125   901   1   2:15.12 m         20   0  49732   2268   1236 1965524  0.2 2191764   0 775      0 4026531839                      `- python3
 9 S 75.6 16125   902   1   2:15.05 m         20   0  49732   2268   1236 1965524  0.2 2191764   0 775      0 4026531839                      `- python3
 3 R 99.9 16125   903   1   2:29.70 m         20   0  52100   2268   1336 1969120  0.2 2195360   0  3k      0 4026531839                      `- python3
 4 S  0.1 15213   904  22   0:00.36 m         20   0  54052   2268   5816 1965528  0.2 2191768   0   0      0 4026531839                      `- python3
15 S  1.2 19285 21279   2  21:27.31 a         20   0  75720   2268  12940  196868  0.3  642876   0   0      0 -                       `- python3
 8 S  0.0 19285 21281   2   0:14.88 a         20   0  75720   2268  12940  196868  0.3  642876   0   0      0 -                           `- python3
10 S  0.9 22118 22120   2  20:07.34 a         20   0  56604   2268   7176  464808  0.2  722164   0   0      0 -                       `- python3
 4 S  0.0 22118 22122   2   0:19.39 a         20   0  56604   2268   7176  464808  0.2  722164   0   0      0 -                           `- python3
 4 S  0.0     2    29   1  33:46.57 root      20   0      0      0      0       0  0.0       0   0   0      0 -           `- rcu_sched
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
top - 22:25:31 up 84 days, 23:06,  4 users,  load average: 3.78, 2.30, 0.97
Threads: 365 total,   4 running, 361 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :   0.2/0.4     1[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu1  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu2  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu3  : 100.0/0.0   100[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]
%Cpu4  :   0.2/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu5  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu6  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu7  : 100.0/0.0   100[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]
%Cpu8  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu9  :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu10 :   0.6/0.4     1[|                                                                                                   ]
%Cpu11 : 100.0/0.0   100[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]
%Cpu12 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu13 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu14 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu15 :   0.6/0.6     1[||                                                                                                  ]
%Cpu16 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu17 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu18 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
%Cpu19 :   0.0/0.0     0[                                                                                                    ]
KiB Mem : 24522940 total, 22076660 free,   772436 used,  1673844 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8257532 total,  7419136 free,   838396 used. 22911364 avail Mem

 P S %CPU  PPID   PID nTH     TIME+ USER      PR  NI    RES   CODE    SHR    DATA %MEM    VIRT vMj vMn   SWAP      nsIPC COMMAND
 2 S  0.2  1614  1671   1  35:40.51 root      20   0    664    740    380    1528  0.0   52272   0   0   1172 -                   `- haproxy
 0 R  0.4 12882  4964   1   0:31.66 m         20   0   2596     96   1524    1596  0.0  158096   0   0      0 4026531839                  `- top
 7 R 99.9 16125   898   1   3:18.45 m         20   0  52608   2268   1336 1969112  0.2 2195352   0   9      0 4026531839                      `- python3
11 R 99.9 16125   899   1   3:18.46 m         20   0  52612   2268   1336 1969116  0.2 2195356   0   9      0 4026531839                      `- python3
 3 R 99.9 16125   903   1   3:18.43 m         20   0  52624   2268   1336 1969120  0.2 2195360   0  10      0 4026531839                      `- python3
15 S  1.2 19285 21279   2  21:27.92 a         20   0  75720   2268  12940  196868  0.3  642876   0   0      0 -                       `- python3
10 S  1.0 22118 22120   2  20:07.81 a         20   0  56604   2268   7176  464808  0.2  722164   0   0      0 -                       `- python3
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
'''
```

Comment: If there's an answer buried in here, it's so buried in off-topic gibberish and unexplained numbers, it's barely noticeable. This isn't even a true HPC scenario, it's a standard workstation, so most of the HPC asides are irrelevant. The summary is "a task that competes on I/O to the same device (lowering I/O throughput), and uses threads in CPython for subsequently CPU bound work (losing more to GIL inefficiencies while gaining nothing), is a terrible idea," but you buried it in low context data with dubious relevance.

Comment: Thanks for your reflection. The person who asked is in a different situation -- with a need, with a previous will to seek a solution, with an unfullfilled expectation from an attempt to parallelise at least some part of the story and she/he will understand the way back to the working solution. GIL is not an issue for that scenario, a possibility to concurrently execute is. Both demonstrated ( step by step, if one tries ) and measured, to compare comparable.